# How to get Kubernetes service IP inside a pod definition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

Using Kubernetes 1.2.1 with Google Cloud. I have a service defined and running. I want to start a pod that gets the cluster IP address for the service. So that I can pass this IP through to a script that runs when the container starts.

From what I have read I can use the form `MYSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST` where MYSERVICE is the name of the service. Here is the Pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mypod
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: mypod
      image: myimage
      env:
        - name: VARIABLE_NAME
          value: MYSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST
```

The script for the image runs this...

```
echo "Variable: $VARIABLE_NAME"
```

when I run `kubectl logs mypod` I see...

```
Variable: MYSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is working correctly. In your pod yaml you are setting the environment variable `VARIABLE_NAME` to `MYSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST` and your script is printing out the value you specified. If you change your script to `echo "MYSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST: $MYSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST"` it should print out the IP that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the K8 env var name in $()

```
- name: VARIABLE_NAME
  value: $(MYSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST)
```